# SQLAlchemy SELECT id FROM Table_1 WHERE name='xyz'

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can get the `SELECT id from parts where name='Part1'` as an SQL statement but what is the way to do that with SQLAlchemy?

I've tried;

```
db.session.query(Parts.id).filter(name=form.name.data)
```

But this returns an Object not the `id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code.

```
parts = db.session.query(Parts).filter(Parts.name==Part1).first()
```

Then if you want the only id you can just access

```
parts.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Store that object in a varaible, and then use dot notation to pull out what you want.  For example:

```
item = db.session.query(Parts.id).filter(name=form.name.data).one()
print item.id
```